# Nginx fastcgi param doesn't get to CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, codeigniter-2, fastcgi

I have set a fastcgi_param `ENVIRONMENT` at nginx virtual host file, but I can't access that value inside CodeIgniter:

```
var_dump(defined('ENVIRONMENT')); //outputs false
```

Full nginx virtual host file:

```
server {
    listen      80;

    # Hostnames alias
    server_name webapp1;

    root /home/edson/repositorios/webapp1;

    index       index.php index.html;

    location /bec/admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /bec/admin/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location /bec {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /bec/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    #
    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
        fastcgi_param ENVIRONMENT development;
    }

    # Nginx Cache Control for Static Files (Browser Cache Control Directives)
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|xls|xlsx|doc|docx|csv|txt)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           max;
    }

    #
    # deny access to .htaccess files, and hidden files, which starts with dot (.), if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show full config

Comment: @AlexeyTen question edited.

Comment: Check $_SERVER array

Comment: @AlexeyTen yep it's there, thought it was suposed to be a PHP constant too, that's how I do it in Zend Framework 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a environment variable, so it can be accessed through [getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):

> Gets the value of an environment variable

#### Example

```
getenv('ENVIRONMENT');
```